# Get Child node attribute by parent in xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Hi I have a xml like below.

```
<Services>
      <Service Name="ReportWriter" AssemplyName="ReportService.ReportWriters" ClassName="ExcelWriter">
        <ServiceConfigurations>
         <Configuration key="key1" value="value1" />
 <Configuration key="key2" value="value2" />

        </ServiceConfigurations>
      </Service>
      <Service Name="LogtWriter" AssemplyName="" ClassName="">
        <ServiceConfigurations>
          <Configuration key="" value="" />
        </ServiceConfigurations>
      </Service>
      <Service Name="OutputHandler" AssemplyName="" ClassName="">
        <ServiceConfigurations>
          <Configuration key="key1" value="value1" />
 <Configuration key="key2" value="value2" />
        </ServiceConfigurations>
      </Service>
</Services>
```

I want to get the configuration key and value attribute for service name= "ReportWriter".

FOR ex- output should be key1, value1, key2, value2 for service name= 'ReportWriter'.

Can anybody help me on  how to achive please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
 Dictionary<string,string> result = xdoc.Descendants("Service")
                  .First(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == "ReportWriter")
                  .Descendants("Configuration")
                  .Select(x => new
                             {
                                 Key = x.Attribute("key").Value,
                                 Value = x.Attribute("value").Value
                             }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value) ;
```

**Update:**

Above query returns a `Dictionary<string,string>`, You can use a `foreach` to iterate through it's elements and add it to your existing dictionary.

Comment: Hi Rahul. This is fine Thanks . If I want to add the key and value to a object of dictionary type. Then what should be the code

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq2Xml and XPath

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var conf = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//Service[@Name='ReportWriter']/ServiceConfigurations/Configuration")
           .Select(c => new { Key = (string)c.Attribute("key"), Value = (string)c.Attribute("value") })
           .ToList();
```

Or without XPath

```
var conf = xDoc.Descendants("Service")
                .First(srv => srv.Attribute("Name").Value == "ReportWriter")
                .Descendants("Configuration")
                .Select(c => new { Key = (string)c.Attribute("key"), Value = (string)c.Attribute("value") })
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
        var result = doc
            .Descendants("Service")               
            .Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == "ReportWriter")
            .Descendants("Configuration")
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Key = x.Attribute("key").Value,
                Value = x.Attribute("value").Value
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```